# Unable to remove tableview's deselected row array value in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, button, tableview

I am using tableview for multiple row selection with checkmark using button. with this code able to add all selected row ids in `arrSelectedRows` and able to remove when deselect.... but here i am adding all selected row JSON title in `arrSubCat` and not able to remove

**code:** in this code `arrSubCat` is array of strings.. in this array i am adding selected row JSON title.. **here the issue is if i deselect the row then unable to remove deselected row title from `arrSubCat` array**

if i try like this `arrSubCat.remove(at: (sender.tag))`

**then error:**

> Fatal error: Index out of range

how to solve this issue.. please do guide

```
 var arrSelectedRows:[Int] = []
 var arrSubCat:[String] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return getSubCategory?.result?.sub_categories?.count ?? 0
}
var removeIndex: Int?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditLangTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell

 let id = getSubCategory?.result?.sub_categories?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0

 if arrSelectedRows.contains(id){
     cell.langSelectButn.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"), for: .normal)

 }else{
     cell.langSelectButn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_inactive"), for: .normal)
}
 cell.langSelectButn.tag = id
 cell.langSelectButn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
return cell
}

@objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
{
print(sender.tag)
if self.arrSelectedRows.contains(sender.tag){
    self.arrSelectedRows.remove(at: self.arrSelectedRows.firstIndex(of: sender.tag)!)
    arrSubCat.remove(at: (sender.tag))

}else{
    
    self.arrSelectedRows.append(sender.tag)
    print("arrayof selected row ids \(arrSelectedRows)")
    if let selectedSubcat = getSubCategory?.result?.sub_categories{
        for singleSubcat in selectedSubcat{
            if sender.tag == singleSubcat.id{
            arrSubCat.append(singleSubcat.title ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
    print("array of subcat title \(arrSubCat)")
}
self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: It's not a good way to use `tag` for accessing cell index. Recommended way is to use protocol. You can get some idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71918049/11088581). I'm a bit busy now. I will give an answer within tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: There are several problems in this code. You set `id` as button's tag where `id` can be a random number. `checkBoxSelection()` method called every time when user select/deselect the button where you are trying to remove item from `arrSubCat` by using 'tag'. Suppose there are 20 items in the list and as the `tag` number is random it might be any number greater than 20 (let's say 78). And when you try to remove 78th element from `arrSubCat` the crash occurs.

Comment: Please share the code of adding selected item in `arrSelectedRows` array and also the code of`EditLangTableVIewCell`.

Comment: @MBT, in `checkBoxSelection ` with this code `self.arrSelectedRows.remove(at: self.arrSelectedRows.firstIndex(of: sender.tag)!)` i am able to remove deselected row `id` the same id's item i need to delete from  `arrSubCat `.. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code of `checkBoxSelection()` method like below

```
if self.arrSelectedRows.contains(sender.tag){
    if let selectedIndex = self.arrSelectedRows.firstIndex(of: sender.tag) {
        self.arrSelectedRows.remove(at: selectedIndex)
        arrSubCat.remove(at: selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Json Swift please let me know if it works or not.